# Phalcon / REST to existing project

Tags: php, rest, phalcon

I developing a phalcon web application which has the following directory structure:

```
  /app/
        /cache/
            ...
        /config/
            config.php
            loader.php
            services.php
        /controllers/
            contorllerBase.php
            ...
        /models/
            ...
        /views/
            ...
    /public/
        /css/
        /img/
        /js/
        .htacces
        index.php
        webtools.config.php
        webtools.php
    index.html
```

I created this project with phalcon devtools, and its work correctly so far, but now i have to implement a REST function to this project. 
My questions are:

- Where I create to REST logic in this structure?
- What is the recommended way to implement REST ?
  Because i want access views and I need rest too (i.e.: http://localhost/api/...)

I found some solution in the internet but they are confusing for me because mostly implement a single REST api without views.

config.php

```
return new \Phalcon\Config(array(
    'database' => array(
...
    ),
    'application' => array(
        'controllersDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/controllers/',
        'modelsDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/models/',
        'viewsDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/views/',
        'pluginsDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/plugins/',
        'libraryDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/library/',
        'cacheDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/cache/',
        'logsDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/logs',
        'baseUri' => '/',
    )
        ));
```

loader.php

```
<?php

$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

/**
 * We're a registering a set of directories taken from the configuration file
 */
$loader->registerDirs(
    array(
        $config->application->controllersDir,
        $config->application->modelsDir
    )
)->register();
```

services.php

```
<?php

use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Url as UrlResolver;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as DbAdapter;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt as VoltEngine;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Metadata\Memory as MetaDataAdapter;
use Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files as SessionAdapter;

/**
 * The FactoryDefault Dependency Injector automatically register the right services providing a full stack framework
 */
$di = new FactoryDefault();

/**
 * The URL component is used to generate all kind of urls in the application
 */
$di->set('url', function () use ($config) {
    $url = new UrlResolver();
    $url->setBaseUri($config->application->baseUri);

    return $url;
}, true);

/**
 * Setting up the view component
 */
$di->set('view', function () use ($config) {

    $view = new View();

    $view->setViewsDir($config->application->viewsDir);

    $view->registerEngines(array(
        '.volt' => function ($view, $di) use ($config) {

            $volt = new VoltEngine($view, $di);

            $volt->setOptions(array(
                'compiledPath' => $config->application->cacheDir,
                'compiledSeparator' => '_'
            ));

            return $volt;
        },
                '.phtml' => 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Php'
            ));

            return $view;
        }, true);

        /**
         * Database connection is created based in the parameters defined in the configuration file
         */
        $di->set('db', function () use ($config) {
            return new DbAdapter(array(
                'host' => $config->database->host,
                'username' => $config->database->username,
                'password' => $config->database->password,
                'dbname' => $config->database->dbname,
                "charset" => $config->database->charset
            ));
        });

        /**
         * If the configuration specify the use of metadata adapter use it or use memory otherwise
         */
        $di->set('modelsMetadata', function () {
            return new MetaDataAdapter();
        });

        /**
         * Start the session the first time some component request the session service
         */
        $di->set('session', function () {
            $session = new SessionAdapter();
            $session->start();

            return $session;
        });
```

index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$debug = new \Phalcon\Debug();
$debug->listen();

try {
    /**
     * Read the configuration
     */
    $config = include __DIR__ . "/../app/config/config.php";

    /**
     * Read auto-loader
     */
    include __DIR__ . "/../app/config/loader.php";

    /**
     * Read services
     */
    include __DIR__ . "/../app/config/services.php";

    /**
     * Handle the request
     */
    $application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);

    echo $application->handle()->getContent();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I really apreciate any kind of help.

Comment: I think I would recommend adding separate `module` providing REST functionalities. But lests wait for answers, maybe somebody has better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used:

**ROUTING**:

In the routing file (routes for non API part)

```
include __DIR__ . '/routes_api.php';
$router->mount($api);
```

In this routes_api I have created a group and defined a namespace of controllers for this group

```
$api = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Group(array(
    'namespace' => '\X\Controllers\API',
));

// --- Base API URL prefix
$api->setPrefix('/api');
```

Routes are defined as usual, in style with a REST service, ex:

```
$api->addGet('/addresses', array('controller' => 'addresses', 'action' => 'listMe'));
```

**CONTROLLERS:**

I have created a folder **api** under controllers, classes are in the namespace as the one defined in group (namespace X\Controllers\API), with a class base which implements some REST courtesy methods for all the REST controllers:

```
class AddressesController extends \X\ApiControllerBase
```

Controller base:

```
class ApiControllerBase extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
```

To provide a custom implementation of JSON style response for all the REST

```
public function initialize()
{
   $this->response = new \X\ApiResponse();
}
```

To provide an authorization gateway for the REST part throug a OAuth server and do some acquisition/filtering/sanitizing on inbound querystring for pagination and other utilities which are available to all the REST controllers i have overrided:

```
public function beforeExecuteRoute($dispatcher)
```

In the controllers actions I return a response using a method that gets data from a paginator in my custom Response implementation (who follow):

```
$this->response->setResponse($paginator);
return $this->response;
```

For the output style then:

```
class ApiResponse extends \Phalcon\Http\Response
{
    public function __construct($content=null, $code=null, $status=null)
    {
        parent::__construct($content, $code, $status);
        $this->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }

    public function setResponse($response, $limit = null, $processitems = null)
    {
        // .... some manipulations of data from controllers ... building of arrays ....
        $this->setContent(json_encode(array('error' => false) + $response));
    }

    public function setResponseError($description, $error = true) {
        //Set status code
        $this->setStatusCode(200, 'OK');
        $this->setContent(json_encode(array('error' => $error, 'error_description' => $description)));
    }
}
```

Is needed a controller to manage requests to **/api** without any rest action, by default it should be named after the route, so it should be ApiController, you can tweak the routing system in order to change that or raise a errors (http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html#inject-model-instances)

**SERVICES:**

In the end, for managing several kind of errors (thrown exceptions as well) with a pretty output as JSON {error: true, message: "...."}, in index.php I have implemented a **beforeException** event of the dispatcher:

```
$di->setShared('dispatcher', function() {
    $eventsManager = new Phalcon\Events\Manager();

    $eventsManager->attach("dispatch", function($event, $dispatcher, $exception) {
        /* @var $dispatcher Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher */
        if ($event->getType() == 'beforeException') {
            $ctrl = $dispatcher->getActiveController();

           if($ctrl instanceof \X\ApiControllerBase) {
                $dispatcher->forward(array(
                    'namespace' => '\\',
                    'controller' => 'error',
                    'action' => 'api',
                    'params' => array('message' => $exception->getMessage())
                ));
                return false;
            }

    $dispatcher = new Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
    //Bind the EventsManager to the Dispatcher
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);

    return $dispatcher;
);
```

Then the error controller, called by dispatcher with a forward method (in this case without namespace, it's inside controllers folder):

```
class ErrorController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller {

    public function route404Action() {
        $this->response->setStatusCode(404 , 'Not Found');
    }

    public function apiAction() {
        $pars = $this->dispatcher->getParams();
        $this->response = new \X\ApiResponse();
        $this->response->setResponseError($pars['message']);
        return $this->response;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, its looks good for me. But when I tried to reproduce your code faced to the error which is write `Test\Controllers\ApiController handler class cannot be loaded`. So far I created api folder inside of controllers. In this directory I created `AdressesController.php`, `ApiControllerBase.php`, `ApiResponse.php` with namspace `Test\Controllers\API` after that I created the routes_api.php and added this to `services.php`:

Comment: this: `$di->set('dispatcher', function() {
$dispatcher = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
$dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace('Test\Controllers');
return $dispatcher;
});
$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
include __DIR__ . '/routes_api.php';
$router->mount($api);`




I think somthing wrong with the routes_api.php.
`<?php

$api = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Group(array(
    'namespace' => 'Test\Controllers\API',
        ));

// --- Base API URL prefix
$api->setPrefix('/api');

$api->addGet('/addresses', array('controller' => 'addresses', 'action' => 'listMe'));`

Comment: If you mean you have used my code as it is, in **beforeException**, remove the part:

    if($ctrl instanceof \ApiController) {
                $dispatcher->forward(array(
                    'namespace' => '\\',
                    'controller' => 'error',
                    'action' => 'api',
                    'params' => array('message' => 'API function not found or call method not supported')
                ));
                return false;
            }

it's a typo

Comment: Edited the answer without the typo and added the error controller.

Comment: I uploaded my project to github because its little hard write in here. https://github.com/eszikk/phalcon
I would appraciet if you take a look on it.

Comment: It's working but when type an incorrect api-url (like: /api/adrssdf) just show me an ampty html page without content. Another question I saw in phalcon webpage there is avaible annotation driven routers. Is possible to apply thes forexample AdressesController,php? http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html#annotations-router

Comment: I have done a push request with the error controller, added in the answer as well, for the annotations question you can use that as well, the examples you have linkes are very similar to your needs.